# Rails Set-Cookie on json API response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, cookies, jwt

Simple token based auth for Rails.
Client server makes a request to the API server.  The API server returns success status, json-encoded body and ideally sets a cookie.

```
# response from API  
render json: {user: "user", token: "token_string"}, status: :created
```

How can this response also set a cookie?
I've tried to append `, set_cookie: token` to the render statement.  I've also
`skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, only: :create`

The end goal is to store the token in a browser cookie.  I do not want to use HTML5 storage for the token.

Comment: The client app should be setting the cookie in this case, not rails.

Comment: Client app receives json body & then sets cookie?  Makes sense but is that standard for an API?  Counting on the client (which can be 3rd parties) to properly handle the token?

Comment: Yes, when it comes to token auth that's how it works. On the server you just want to check that each request has the token and possibly have rules for when/if the token expires.

Comment: @Nathan that is not correct. When you use a secure, httpOnly cookie as part of your CSRF/XSS protection of an API for a SPA, which is what the OP is trying to do from the looks of it, you do NOT want the client to ever have access to the cookie.
If they did any XSS script would also gain access and the protection would be 0. The security here is based on the server and browser having a contract that the client code CAN NOT gain access to. Read the OWASP guidelines for more: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Double_Submit_Cookie

Answer (score 16):

This is my setup for a cross-domain SPA/API setup:

I have this in my controller, using the Knock gem, action:

```
class AccountTokenController < Knock::AuthTokenController
  def  create
    response.set_cookie(
      :jwt,
      {
        value: auth_token.token,
        expires: 30.minutes.from_now,
        path: '/api',
        secure: Rails.env.production?,
        httponly: Rails.env.production?
      }
    )

    render json: auth_token.payload, status: :created
  end
end
```

That will set a cookie on the client as well as returning all the token data in the response body, including a CSRF token.

You also need to make sure that your AJAX requests include the cookie, which they don't by default. With Axios, you do this by setting the option `withCredentials: true`. For other libraries, it will be something similar.

## CORS

If you have CORS configured on the API server, and you should, you need some additional config there as well. I use the `Rack::CORS` gem for this and my config looks like this (config/initializers/cors.rb):

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins 'http://localhost:3001'
    resource '*',
      headers: :any,
      methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head],
      credentials: true
  end
end
```

Note the config for `credentials: true` as well as the need to specify a specific host under `origins`, neither `*` nor a list of domains will work in this case.

## CSRF and XSS

Very basically Cross-Site Request Forgery is when another domain makes a request to your backend on the assumption that your user is logged in and has a session cookie. So it is based on cookies and come from a third party domain and as such can not access anything in your browser.

XSS, Cross-Site Scripting is when someone manages to run a script on YOUR page, and hence your domain. This sort of attack can access anything in your browser, for that domain. This includes sessionStorage and localStorage as well as normal cookies that the browser can read.

## Why this works

The CSRF token is present both in the session cookie and sent along with each API request as a header, giving protection from both CORS and XSS while keeping the backend stateless.

All any backend service has to do is:

1. Verify the JWT signature (to ensure it's not a faked or manipulated session cookie being returned).
2. Verify the `exp` part to avoid JWT replay.
3. Compare the header CSRF token to the one in the JWT.
4. Verify the scopes in the JWT (this will be application specific).

The full JWT is signed with the servers private key before being used as a cookie and as such cannot be manipulated without detection.

So any CSRF attack will fail since it only has indirect access to the session cookie and won't be able to read the CSRF token from it, so any request will fail.

Any XSS attack will fail because even though they can read the CSRF token in localStorage they can not get the session cookie. The only way to do that would be to run requests from your browser session against the backend, and while that could be possible that is not generally how these attacks work. They normally try to export the session info so that they can make requests from another server, and that won't work here.

Comment: Hi Jonas, why are you using this bit? Is there a reason we're only using secure cookies in production? Why not in staging or dev?
```
        secure: Rails.env.production?,
        httponly: Rails.env.production?
```

Comment: @bishal you generally do not want to send a secure cookie unless its video HTTPS. If you're developing your application with HTTP you'll get a warning about sending secure cookies through the HTTP. Assuming you're using HTTPS on production, then thats a good time to send your cookies as secure.

Comment: I still cannot really figure out how this protection works. Could you providing some examples on what exactly server has to do to protect from it. Since XSS can make requests on you behalf they can make everything.